Using H-Bridge as a way to drive a latching solenoid that requires reverse polarity pulses


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have been working on an Arduino project which requires me to control a latching solenoid through pins on the Arduino uno. The solenoid needs reverse polarity to switch position and requires a quick pulse in shifting. Additionally, the solenoid requires about 9 V of power at 0.3 A so I hope to use the Arduino as a switch for a battery supplying the voltage and current. In this, I thought an H-bridge to be the most effective way to achieve this and wanted to work out a basic model for opinions. I have done some reading on H-bridges as well as flyback diode to protect back EMF and was wondering if an H-bridge (I have an L293D H-bridge) with diodes would work. I am very new to electronics and appreciate any help and was just hoping I could get some advice on the idea and how I plan on executing it.
Edit: Sorry if the diagram is really ugly and that the values aren't represented (I also used CCVSs to represent Arduino pins). I just wanted to try and make one to help show my idea.

Here i have redrawn your circuit - Hamo

simulate this circuit
(This schematic above by Hamo has been added into the question as a template which you can use (or not - it's your choice) as the basis for improving/replacing the original one. If you don't want to use it, you can delete it. If you do want to use it, then consider deleting the original schematic and make any changes/updates to that one from Hamo.)

N-ch mosfets cannot be used on high-side without driver. I would use P-ch on high-side for such a simple selenoid drive.

A misleading/badly formed schematic is not helping with getting a design idea across at all. Actually it can be argued it makes it harder to get an idea across.

that's an awful schematic ... stop tying all grounds together ... use multiple separate ground symbols ... also, do not cross multiple lines that belong to the same node

If it's a H-bridge then draw it like a H-bridge. The clue's in the name.

90seb57 - Hi, Site member Hamo kindly made a basic H-bridge schematic for you to use as the basis for improving/replacing your original schematic. It was posted as an "answer", yet does not answer your question :( Therefore it has been deleted as an answer. However to avoid losing that effort by Hamo, I have copied it into the question. You can decide whether to use their work as a template for an improved schematic (or not). Leave a reference for their work (e.g. "Based on a schematic by "Hamo") if you do use any part of it.

Thank you SamGibson for leaving Hamo's work up there. It was my first time making a schematic so I didn't really know how to make it look nice or the rules(like not tying all the grounds together as MrGerber said). I will gladly use Mr. Hamo's design as my basis and am super thankful for his help. Also I am thankful for the people who added criticism to my design as it helps me improve as well as the comments on the P channel MOSFETs instead of N.

Yes, L293D will work here, but it has a large voltage drop across the bipolar output transistors.
The source output saturation voltage is 1.4 V and sink output saturation voltage is 1.2 V, so 2.6 V are lost across the transistors. You would need a minimum supply voltage of 11.6 V to deliver 9 V at the solenoid.
Since you suggested using a MOSFET bridge, consider using a modern H-bridge IC with such an output stage like DRV8212, TMI8870, A4950, ZXBM5210, DRV8220.
The internal body diodes of the MOSFETs can carry the back EMF of your solenoid during the MOSFET dead time, separate diodes are not required in your application.

Thank you for the information on the L293D on the voltage loss. I will consider the H-Bridges you suggested as well as note the lack of separate diodes needed. If I may ask, if you were to build a circuit like this is there any improvement you think you would add. I would want to make this circuit the best way I could for the purpose so I want to improve it as much as I could. Dont worry about putting a lot of though into any improvements if there are any at all, I am grateful for your help and knowledge already immensely and will use it in my project.

Well, don't forget a proper supply decoupling capacitor at the driver IC, in your case 10 µF / 25V ceramic for the sharp edges and a bulk electrolytic cap. To reduce EMI issues I like to add a series connected R/C snubber element between the solenoid connectors, say 10 ohm and 100 nF.
